# python installed code stops working and reinstalling doesnt work

Tags: python, virtualenv, setup.py

I have a system where on boot my code updates and installs into a virtualenv.

normally i need to run it as follows

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ program.py
```

program.py is an executable. Sometimes I find (due to power cuts / bad reboots) that my code reaches a state wherein when i run program.py it exits without giving any output.

When i try re-installing the previously cloned code, it exits saying it cannot find my module.

```
(venv)$ program.py
Traceback cannot find module "clientbox"
```

which is the name of my module which program.py is a part of.
Does anyone know why this could occur and how i could fix this.
Currently the only way that i have been able to fix this is by re-cloning the code and re-installing.

Comment: Do you mean clone as in `git clone`? If you have version control, you can easily find out what changed (and if you don't, you are wasting your time, and possibly ours).

Comment: Yes, i did do git diff, and there were no changes, git status also mentioned that there were no changes. But the code on installation wouldnt work.